# Google Drive API v3 updating a file on the go (using realtime data) in python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I am trying to update a file that I created with some new data. Essentially, i am trying to append contents to an already created file. I have tried different ways using different attributes but nothing seems to work so far. The migration from v2 to v3 seems to have made things harder to develop in python.

This is my code so far

```
def updateFile(fileID, contents):
    credentials = get_credentials() #this function gets the credentials for oauth
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
    # First retrieve the file from the API.

    #fileCreated = service.files().get(fileId=fileID).execute()
    #print(dir(fileCreated.update()))
    # File's new content.
    file_metadata = { 'name' : 'notes.txt', 'description' : 'this is a test' }
    fh  = BytesIO(contents.encode())
    media = MediaIoBaseUpload(fh,
                        mimetype='text/plain')
    # Send the request to the API.
    #print(BytesIO(contents.encode()).read())
    print(fileID)
    updated_file = service.files().update(
        body=file_metadata,
        #uploadType = 'media',
        fileId=fileID,
        #fields = fileID,
        media_body=media).execute()
```

I have tried using MediaFileUpload (it works only for uploading a file) but I am appending a 'string' that is real time generated using a voice interface and is not stored in any file. So I ended up using MediaIoBaseUpload.

The code runs without any error, but the file is not updated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Upload is probably going to upload a new file have you checked if you have several files with the same name?

Comment: @DaImTo, no i dont have any duplicate files with the same name. The mediaFileUpload takes file as a parameter to upload but the MediaIoBaseUpload takes a byte stream with MIME type to upload into the drive. I am unsure why this fails in my case.

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation about it. https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseUpload-class.html

Answer (score 0):

okay, so i figured out what was wrong with my code. Apparently, nothing is wrong with this chunk of code that I posted. I realized that I have not converted the document I created to a "google document" hence the code didnt update the document. I changed the mime type of the document i create to be a google document, and now the code works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `service.files().get_media(fileId=fileID).execute()` to get the file content and append new content to it.